# Distributed training initialisation of pytorch based on srun

Tags: pytorch, distributed, hpc

I try to run pytorch on a cluster which is managed by srun, I follow the ddp examples here (https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/distributed/ddp). It works for me when I set one node and use multiple processes (each process access one gpu). Here are the results:

```
$ srun -C gpu -N 1 -c 8 -n 1 --gpus-per-task=4 python -m torch.distributed.launch --nnode=1 --nproc_per_node=4 example.py --local_world_size=4 
srun: job 2520346 queued and waiting for resources
srun: job 2520346 has been allocated resources
[7288] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '0', 'WORLD_SIZE': '4'}
[7289] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '1', 'WORLD_SIZE': '4'}
[7290] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '2', 'WORLD_SIZE': '4'}
[7291] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '3', 'WORLD_SIZE': '4'}
[7288]: world_size = 4, rank = 0, backend=nccl 
[7288] rank = 0, world_size = 4, n = 1, device_ids = [0] 
[7290]: world_size = 4, rank = 2, backend=nccl 
[7290] rank = 2, world_size = 4, n = 1, device_ids = [2] 
[7289]: world_size = 4, rank = 1, backend=nccl 
[7289] rank = 1, world_size = 4, n = 1, device_ids = [1] 
[7291]: world_size = 4, rank = 3, backend=nccl 
[7291] rank = 3, world_size = 4, n = 1, device_ids = [3] 
*****************************************
Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable for each process to be 1 in default, to avoid your system being overloaded, please further tune the variable for optimal performance in your application as needed. 
*****************************************
```

However, when I try 2 nodes and each nodes can access 4 gpu, the program hangs there

```
srun -C gpu -N 2 -c 8 -n 2 --gpus-per-task=4 python -m torch.distributed.launch --nnode=2 --nproc_per_node=4 example.py --local_world_size=4 
srun: job 2520347 queued and waiting for resources
srun: job 2520347 has been allocated resources
[62582] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '0', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[62583] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '1', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[62585] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '2', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[62586] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '3', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[48801] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '0', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[48829] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '1', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[48849] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '2', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[48850] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '3', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
```

I'm not sure how pytorch works in details for initialising the env here, but I guess that the master addr should not be the 127.0.0.1 for the second scenario, because there are two different nodes. Do you know how to make the example work in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some explorations, I found one solution and I put it here. Maybe there are better solutions, but this solution seems work to me currently. I write a MPI program which can detect the address of eth (in my case, it is eth3), and then the mpi program broadcast the leader addr to all workers, and then the mpi program use system call to start the python script.

here is the mpi program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>


std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
    if (!pipe) {
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
        result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank, procs;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procs);

    std::string ipcommand="ifconfig eth3 | egrep -o 'inet [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'  | cut -d' ' -f2";

    std::string ipaddr = exec(ipcommand.c_str());

    std::cout << "rank is " << rank << " ip addr is " << ipaddr << std::endl;
    
    //get master ip
    char masterAddr[128];
    if(rank==0){
        strcpy(masterAddr,ipaddr.c_str());
    }

    MPI_Bcast(masterAddr,128,MPI_CHAR,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    //std::cout << "rank is " << rank << " ip addr is " << ipaddr << " master ip is " << std::string(masterAddr)<< std::endl;

    std::string pytorchcommand = "/bin/bash ../rundistributed.sh " + std::to_string(rank) + " " + std::string(masterAddr);

    std::cout << "pytorchcommand: " << pytorchcommand << std::endl;

    system(pytorchcommand.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

here is the content in the `rundistributed.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#$1 is the rank id
#$2 is the master addr

python -m torch.distributed.launch \
    --nnode=2 --nproc_per_node=4 --node_rank=$1\
    --master_addr="$2" ../distributed4.py --local_world_size=4
```

here are the results:

```
$ srun -C gpu -N 2 -c 8 -n 2 --gpus-per-task=4 ./initrank 
srun: job 2520882 queued and waiting for resources
srun: job 2520882 has been allocated resources
rank is 1 ip addr is 192.168.174.14

rank is 0 ip addr is 192.168.174.13

pytorchcommand: /bin/bash ../rundistributed.sh 1 192.168.174.13

pytorchcommand: /bin/bash ../rundistributed.sh 0 192.168.174.13

[37240] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '192.168.174.13', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '6', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[37238] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '192.168.174.13', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '4', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[78961] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '192.168.174.13', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '0', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[37239] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '192.168.174.13', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '5', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[78963] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '192.168.174.13', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '2', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[78962] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '192.168.174.13', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '1', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[37241] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '192.168.174.13', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '7', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[78964] Initializing process group with: {'MASTER_ADDR': '192.168.174.13', 'MASTER_PORT': '29500', 'RANK': '3', 'WORLD_SIZE': '8'}
[37241]: world_size = 8, rank = 7, backend=gloo 
[78962]: world_size = 8, rank = 1, backend=gloo 
[78963]: world_size = 8, rank = 2, backend=gloo 
[78961]: world_size = 8, rank = 0, backend=gloo 
[78964]: world_size = 8, rank = 3, backend=gloo 
[37238]: world_size = 8, rank = 4, backend=gloo 
[37240]: world_size = 8, rank = 6, backend=gloo 
[37239]: world_size = 8, rank = 5, backend=gloo 
[37241] rank = 7, world_size = 8, attachedDevice = 1, device_ids = [3] 
[78961] rank = 0, world_size = 8, attachedDevice = 1, device_ids = [0] 
[78964] rank = 3, world_size = 8, attachedDevice = 1, device_ids = [3] 
[78963] rank = 2, world_size = 8, attachedDevice = 1, device_ids = [2] 
[78962] rank = 1, world_size = 8, attachedDevice = 1, device_ids = [1] 
[37239] rank = 5, world_size = 8, attachedDevice = 1, device_ids = [1] 
[37240] rank = 6, world_size = 8, attachedDevice = 1, device_ids = [2] 
[37238] rank = 4, world_size = 8, attachedDevice = 1, device_ids = [0] 
*****************************************
Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable for each process to be 1 in default, to avoid your system being overloaded, please further tune the variable for optimal performance in your application as needed. 
*****************************************
*****************************************
Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable for each process to be 1 in default, to avoid your system being overloaded, please further tune the variable for optimal performance in your application as needed. 
*****************************************
```